# Observe payment_method_is_active only for front end not working

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am trying to hide some specific payment method from frontend only.
I have tried with `observer` and `plugin`.
Both working fine if my `di.xml` and `events.xml` placed in global config i.e

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
>
> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

**Problem** is, if I move them to frontend they stop working.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml
>
> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I have written blog about **How to Disable Payment Method in frontend** only..
Please check this.. I am sure this will be very useful to you.

This module is having functionality to disable payment module from admin configuration of payment method.
You just need to **'Disable in Frontend' => 'Yes'** and payment method will be disable from frontend.

Check: http://kachagopal.blogspot.com/2018/08/hide-payment-method-from-front-end-in.html

Comment: Thank you @Gopal, for sharing tutorial. my question is why observer is not working only for front. as I can see you also put your events.xml in global and check area in observer class.